# Connecting to SQL server on a virtual machine is more computationally expensive than a dedicated SQL instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server, azure

I have two options:

I can connect my web app to a SQL server hosted on a virtual machine, or I can connect it to a dedicated SQL server instance. All will be hosted in the same zones in Azure / AWS e.g.

Now I want to write to this SQL server ten million times in a row in a foreach loop.

Will the dedicated SQL server instance perform better than the virtual machine or will it not make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

One great thing about cloud is you can try things out yourself. You haven't described your scenario particularly well - do you mean a database instance on the same virtual machine as the application server?

The answer is - it depends on many factors. Network latency, query complexity, etc.

Comment: Before going to that effort I thought someone might already know. I thought a five minute question and answer might beat spending half a day setting up a VM, installing SQL server on the VM, setting up a SQL instance, setting up a web app, creating connections to both which is often more painful than it should be and then trial running everything. But no, the application would not be on the same instance as the VM.

Comment: I assumed you were asking about something you had already set up. It really will depend on many factors such as latency and query complexity.